# groovy class cannot be resolved to a type in java code

Tags: java, maven, groovy

I created simple maven project to use both groovy code and Java code. However, when I try to create object from groovy class in java code, I got error 'cannot be resolved to a type'

## Payload.groovy

```
package local.myarea.test
class Payload {
    def firstName
    def lastName
}
```

## Test.java

```
package local.myarea.test
public class Test {
    public Test() {
        Payload payloadObj = new Payload();
    }
}
```

structure files of my code:

> src/main/java
>
> > local.myarea.test
> >
> > > Test.java
>
> src/main/groovy
>
> > local.myarea.test
> >
> > > Payload.groovy

Comment: Is that really a folder called `local.myarea.test` or do you have a proper `local/myarea/test` folder structure under both `src/main` and `src/groovy`?

Comment: that's folder, I decided to wipe out and rewrite clean code and not see error. Still don't know what is wrong at first place. Thanks.

Comment: Well it won't work if you don't have a proper folder structure (folder per package path) so put that back first.